как в командной строке создать скрипт, который будет создавать папки с проверкой если они созданы?
надо создать скрипты которые:

Первый скрипт называется First.bat.
Этот скрипт должен создать небольшую древовидную структуру. Вот предварительный просмотр результата:


CURRENT_PATH\FirstNAME>tree .\ /a
Структура папок
Серийный номер тома: 
CURRENT_PATH\firstNAME
+---Примечания
+---Ссылки
\---Прочее


2.1. Дерево создается в текущем местоположении
2.2. Папка Firstname создается на основе полученного параметра.
2.3. Папки Примечания, Ссылки и Прочее должны быть созданы как прямые дочерние элементы папки FirstName.

Этот скрипт получает один параметр
3.1. Это имя, которое должно заменить FirstName.
3.2. Если условия для создания этой папки соблюдены, скрипт выводит следующее сообщение:
Создание папки .
3.3. Это сообщение должно быть точным (замена  правильным значением).
3.4. Новая папка создается в текущем местоположении.
3.5. Пример, запущенный для создания папки Anna :


C:\Firsts.bat anna
Создание файла anna.
C:\tree anna /a
Структура папок
Серийный номер тома:.
C:\anna
+---Примечания
+---Ссылки
\---Прочее



если папка курса уже существует (в предыдущем примере это anna), скрипт должен:
4.1. Создать резервную копию с именем Backup_<имя папки>_<Дата>
4.1.1. заменить значения в угловых скобках реальными значениями.
4.1.2. Эта копия должна находиться в папке пользователя
4.2. Если резервная копия уже существует (включая дату в названии):
4.2.1. Скрипт пишет сообщение об ошибке (без акцента, с точкой, без пробелов в начале и конце):
«Невозможно создать папку <имя_папки>, поскольку она уже существует. »
Пример :
Невозможно создать папку anna, поскольку она уже существует.
4.2.2. Скрипт завершается с кодом ошибки 1.
4.3. Если резервная копия не существовала, скрипт работает и отображает точное сообщение:
Резервная копия папки  в расположении .
Пример :
Резервная копия папки anna в папке c:\users\Backup_anna.
4.4. После успешного резервного копирования удаляем папку старую anna , прежде чем продолжить
Шаг 2
Второй скрипт, тот, который будет вызывать первый скрипт
Второй скрипт называется Second.bat
Скрипт должен создать дерево, используя первый скрипт First.bat.
2.1. Если два сценария будут находиться в одном каталоге.
Second.bat получит ровно 5 аргументов
3.1. Первое — это имя группы
3.2. Следующие 4 — это нимена студентов
3.3. Таким образом, сценарий Second.bat вызовет сценарий First.bat 4 раза, создав таким образом 4 имени в
папке.
2-й
Сценарий Second.bat также должен проверить, существует ли папка, которую он должен создать.
4.1. Если да, выполняется  процедура, что и для первого сценария.
4.2. Исключением является то, что для этого сценария код ошибки должен быть 10.
4.3. Он не должен проверять существование подпапок, это работа первого скрипта.
Вот пример использования и ожидаемый результат.


c:\Second.bat math anna1 anna2 anna3 anna4
C:
+---math
+---anna1
+---Примечания
+---Ссылки
---Прочее
+---anna2
+---Примечания
+---Ссылки
---Прочее
+---anna3
+---Примечания
+---Ссылки
---Прочее
---anna4
+---Примечания
+---Ссылки
---Прочее


Скрипт Second.bat должен создать файл Second.log в текущей папке.
5.1. Если он уже существует, мы создаем его заново (перезаписываем).

Скрипт Second.bat должен записать в файл Second.log:
6.1. Сообщение о том, что создается папка сеанса.
6.2. друг другу сообщения (в том числе сделанные скриптом First.bat)
6.3. Результат в виде вывода команды дерева.

Сценарий отобразит сообщение о завершении выполнения сценария.
Конец создания папки math.

По окончании скрипта мы должны оказаться в том же месте, где и до его запуска.

использовать команду CALL для вызова сценария из другого сценария.


Вызов Second.bat имя_курса
2.  сценарии всегда должны завершаться как минимум с EXIT /B 0.
3. В вызываемом скрипте ставить setlocal и endlocal.
4. В вызывающем скрипте не ставьте setlocal и endlocal
Для вызываемого скрипта:
@эхо выключено
Установить локальный
:: ваш код
Энд локальный
Выход /B 0

Вы хотите готовый результат, не приложив усилий. StackOverflow это не про готовые результаты, а про помощь когда что-то не работает. Огромные вопросы никто читать не будет. А уж тем более, огромное количество кода тоже писать никто не будет, так ещё и на batch.
